# Cassandra timestamp 8bytes

Tags: timestamp, cassandra

I understand that time stamp is there for eventual consistency but there are some cases where consistency is required per row not for each cell. In this case 8bytes per cell is just wastage of both disk and memory.

Is there any way to get rid of time stamp for cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the per-cell timestamp is an inherent consequence of Cassandra being schema-less.  Your application might only write a complete row at a time, but Cassandra doesn't know that.  It has to allow the possibility that someone might come along later and overwrite one of the columns in your row.  That column would then need its own timestamp.

Compression (forthcoming in Cassandra 1.0) should reduce the overhead of repeated timestamps.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-47.